# I'm learning C and I've made a simple program. It doesn't work and I need a an answer

Tags: c, windows, error-handling, stack, codeblocks

I'm learning C and I've made a simple program, and it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    system("title test");
    printf("Arguments: %i\n", argc);
    for (int i, int i <= %s, argv[i], i++){
        switch (%s, argv[i]){
        case 1:
            printf("First Argument: %s\n", argv)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm planning to add more to it, but first I need to figure out what's wrong. Please reply to this question with an answer. I may not reply for a while, since I'm going to bed soon. Sorry if I'm breaking any rules, I'm new to Stack Overflow and I haven't read the rules yet, if there are any.

By the way, here are the error things:

```
| 7|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'|
| 7|error: expected expression before ',' token|
| 8|error: expected expression before '%' token|
|11|error: expected ';' before '}' token|
|  |=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `for (int i, int i <= %s, argv[i], i++){` You sure this is not a typo? Also please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Format specifiers are needed for `printf()` and family, not for every variable representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your program:

- `%s` does not make any sense
- `for (int i, int i <= %s, argv[i], i++)` is wrong and ddoes not make any sense.
- a `break` was missing in your `case`. It doesn't harm here, but as soon as you add more `case`s you'll run into trouble.
- you want `i < argc`, `argc` is at least 1 because `argv[0]` is the name of the program.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  system("title test");
  printf("Arguments: %i\n", argc);
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {  // use i < argc
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
      printf("First Argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
      break;   // this was missing
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

BTW switch/case should be replaced by if here:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
      printf("First Argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First ,the syntaxe of switch is like this :

```
switch (expression)
​{
    case constant1:
    // statements
     break;

   case constant2:
    // statements
    break;
   .
   .
   .
   default:
     // default statements
}
```

How does the switch statement work?

The expression is evaluated once and compared with the values of each case label.

If there is a match, the corresponding statements after the matching label are executed. For example, if the value of the expression is equal to constant2, statements after case constant2: are executed until break is encountered.
If there is no match, the default statements are executed.

If we do not use break, all statements after the matching label are executed.

By the way, the default clause inside the switch statement is optional.

Second:

The syntaxe of for loop is :

```
 for(int i=(First value of control);i<=(Final value of control);Increment of control variable)
```

Example:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
```